# Disk partition failed when trying to install in dual boot

Tags: live-usb, gparted, partitioning

I tried partitioning the disk using the Gparted, so I live booted Linux and tried it. But it failed. Clicking apply the changes it said:

> /dev/sda1 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
>
> e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck.

Comment: What Ubuntu is there on the Live USB ?  What happens if you choose Erase Disk during the installation? Show output examples.

Comment: 16.04 Ubuntu is on the disk as suggested by "heynnema" in the answers i will try booting 17.04 and try it, if it didn't work i will do what you have asked me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer version of e2fsck because of the special needs of your disk configuration. The fix is to use Ubuntu 16.10 Live DVD/USB, or newer.